# How do I launch a TFS build from the command line, specfying both a Changeset and a Shelveset?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build

From the command line, I want to be able to launch a new build (happens to be use XAML build definition) where I can override both the Changeset to start with, and apply a specific Shelveset before building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following settings:

- TFS url to your collection: http://tfscomputer:8080/tfs/mycollection
- Team project name: MyTeamProject
- Build definition: NameOfBuildDefinition
- Changeset: C654321
- Shelveset: CoolChanges

.. Then you can use the follow `tfsbuild.exe` command:

```
tfsbuild.exe
    start
    /collection:http://tfscomputer:8080/tfs/mycollection
    /buildDefinition:"\MyTeamProject\NameOfBuildDefinition"
    /getOption:Custom
    /customGetVersion:C654321
    /shelveset:CoolChanges
    /queue
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will.  I just need to wait until I can.  there's a time limit

Comment: You could mark your reply as an answer, which will also helps others in the community.